# How to enable drag and drop and allow the user custom sorting?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that is a list of user-inputted "Steps" and these steps can be in any order the user wants by drag and drop. I have a TextView that shows the adapter position(the step ordering), but I'm having a hard time keeping it updated after drag and drop.

Using `ItemTouchHelper`, I have the following:

```
override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean
{
    val fromPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
    val toPosition = target.adapterPosition
    if(fromPosition < toPosition)
    {
        for(i in fromPosition until toPosition)
        {
            Collections.swap(data, i, i + 1)
            data[toPosition].number = toPosition.toLong()
            data[fromPosition].number = fromPosition.toLong()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(i in toPosition downTo fromPosition)
        {
            Collections.swap(data, i, i - 1)
            data[toPosition].number = toPosition.toLong()
            data[fromPosition].number = fromPosition.toLong()
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
    notifyItemChanged(toPosition)
    notifyItemChanged(fromPosition)
    return true
}
```

But, it throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException if I drag any item to the first position, and the data inside the EditText isn't maintained across moves or copies itself into the other EditText.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your for loop

```
for(i in toPosition downTo fromPosition)
```

should be

```
for(i in fromPosition downTo toPosition )
```

Comment: Ok, that fixed the IndexOutOfBoundsException, thank you. I still have the data being copied across Views. I tried doing 1) Collections.swap 2) Swapping the step numbers only, but still the EditText data makes copies of across the data(specifically the ones being swapped.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I was being an idiot and trying to fly before I ran. The above code from [this article](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf) would have worked perfectly had I not modified it before testing and running it, apart from calling notifyItemChanged() after notifyItemMoved() because the number relies on the ViewHolder's adapter position. All I had to do was not put any code after Collections.swap(). Now the ordering feature works perfectly.

```
if (fromPosition < toPosition)
    {
        for (i in fromPosition until toPosition)
        {
            swap(data, i, i + 1)
        }
    } else
    {
        for (i in fromPosition downTo toPosition + 1)
        {
            swap(data, i, i - 1)
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
    notifyItemChanged(toPosition)
    notifyItemChanged(fromPosition)
    return true
```